# How to convert int to string without stdlib in Ballerina?

Tags: ballerina

I would like to convert int to string:

```
int count = 1;
string val = <string>count;
```

the above gives me `'int' cannot be cast to 'string'`

Is there a utility method to achieve this. I always have to search for this solution and thought this question would document the answer.

I think I can maybe use `io:sprintf` and I can print using `,` separation in `io:println`, but I would like to do this without stdlib.

Also in Ballerina we cannot concat a string and int as follows:

```
string val = "hello " + count;
```

what is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `toString()` to convert `int` to `string`.

```
int count = 1;
string val = count.toString();
```

Comment: Coming from a java background, I didn't think of invoking function on an `int`. In java it is a primitive type.

Comment: `int` is also a sort of primitive type in Ballerina, it's just for simple types like `int`, `string` and so on, Ballerina have a syntactic sugar that allow invoking `Ballerina langlib` functions using method invocation syntax. This is as same as invoking `import ballerina/lang.value;
string s = value:toString(1);`